# The teaser "more" link is broken

Tags: views, nodes

The teaser "more" link is broken for user blog posts that appear on the homepage. The broken link goes to the root page (www.domain.org).

The title links correctly link to the the node.

I'm using Drupal 7.14, Garland, and the feeds_block block to display the blog posts on the homepage.  It looks like the "more" link is created by Views.  It does this even if I have the "more" field turned off!

How can I fix this?